# When to use「恐れ入りますが」、「申し訳ないが」、「すみませんが」?

Tags: usage

In mails when explaining the cause of a delay etc, I receive something like the following.

> 「。。。のため、少々の遅れが発生します。
>
> 恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願い致します。」

or

> 「。。。申し訳ないが、よろしくお願い致します。」

is there a difference or are they pretty much the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the main differences is that 申し訳ない coveys a sense of apology, for example if something wrong has been done from the speaker to the listener (now, that this expression is being constantly overused in Japan even for the slightest thing is just my opinion and a different story :) ).

On the other hand, 恐れ入りますが doesn't mean something wrong has been done to the listener but the speaker is showing consideration/concern towards the listener when for example making a request.

[This link](https://careerpark.jp/30792) has really a lot of useful info about these two expressions. Let me quote below just one part about the difference, which is mostly what you are asking aboug.

> 「申し訳ございませんが」は「恐れ入りますが」と違い、相手に対して自分の謝罪の気持ちを伝える際に使います。「申し訳ございませんが」は、相手に対して失礼があったり、迷惑がかかった場合に使われるのです。
>
> 「恐れ入りますが」は、自分は悪くないけど相手に配慮するために使う言葉です。「申し訳ございませんが」と似てはいますが、意味はまったく異なるので注意してください。

Let me add some more. It's interesting to notice that apparently 恐れ入りますが is often mistakenly used. For example, always according to the source above, it cannot be used related to the speaker's personal behavior:

> 「恐れ入りますが」の間違った使い方としてよく挙げられるのは、自分の行いに対して「恐れ入りますが」を使ってしまうケースです。「恐れ入りますが」は目上の人や客人に対して頼み事をする際に使う言葉であり、自分の行いに対する言葉ではありません。
>
> 例えば、「恐れ入りますが、私が○○○をしてもよろしいでしょうか」という使い方は間違いです。この文章の場合、行動するのは自分自身であり、相手に頼み事をしているわけではないですよね。この場合は、「申し訳ございませんが」と言う方が正解になります。

And for example the following are examples of **wrong** usage:

> ・恐れ入りますが、もうすぐ会議が始まるので、後ほど折り返しご連絡を差し上げてもよろしいでしょうか。
>
> ・恐れ入りますが、もう少々お待ちください。
>
> ・恐れ入りますが、入金は来週まで待っていただけないでしょうか。